# How to filter the recyclerlistview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi in the code I am using recyclerview to displaying a listview .I am calling the APi and rending the list .But in that list contains data are chnaging with the content.

I want to filter the list and display it into single list item

For example list items contains name and details and unique no.want to display all the contents are name

sample json response:

```
"blocks": [
                        {
                            "label": "Basic Information",
                            "fields": [
                                {
                                    "name": "sales_stage",
                                    "value": "Opportunity",
                                    "label": "Sales Stage",
                                    "uitype": "15",
                                    "type": {
                                        "defaultValue": null
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "potentialname",
                                    "value": "GVN hospital-Falco",
                                    "label": "Opportunity Name",
                                    "uitype": "2",
                                    "type": {
                                        "defaultValue": null
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "assigned_user_id",
                                    "value": {
                                        "value": "19x84",
                                        "label": "Chandra Mouli N"
                                    },
                                    "label": "Assigned To",
                                    "uitype": "53",
                                    "type": {
                                        "defaultValue": {
                                            "value": "19x1",
                                            "label": "Administrator"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },

                                {
                                    "name": "potential_no",
                                    "value": "GW/OPP/100743",
                                    "label": "Opportunity Number",
                                    "uitype": "4",
                                    "type": {
                                        "defaultValue": null
                                    }
                                }
                                {"label": "Products",
                            "fields": [
                                {
                                    "name": "productid",
                                    "value": {
                                        "value": "14x33080",
                                        "label": "CS 30"
                                    },
                                    "label": "Item Name",
                                    "uitype": "10",
                                    "type": {
                                        "defaultValue": null
                                    }
                                },]
                                }
                                ]
                                }]

                                 "blocks": [
                        {
                            "label": "Basic Information",
                            "fields": [
                                {
                                    "name": "sales_stage",
                                    "value": "Opportunity",
                                    "label": "Sales Stage",
                                    "uitype": "15",
                                    "type": {
                                        "defaultValue": null
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "potentialname",
                                    "value": "GVN hospital-Falco",
                                    "label": "Opportunity Name",
                                    "uitype": "2",
                                    "type": {
                                        "defaultValue": null
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "assigned_user_id",
                                    "value": {
                                        "value": "19x84",
                                        "label": "Chandra Mouli N"
                                    },
                                    "label": "Assigned To",
                                    "uitype": "53",
                                    "type": {
                                        "defaultValue": {
                                            "value": "19x1",
                                            "label": "Administrator"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "potential_no",
                                    "value": "GW/OPP/100743",
                                    "label": "Opportunity Number",
                                    "uitype": "4",
                                    "type": {
                                        "defaultValue": null
                                    }
                                }]
                                {"label": "Products",
                            "fields": [
                                {
                                    "name": "productid",
                                    "value": {
                                        "value": "14x33080",
                                        "label": "CS 30"
                                    },
                                    "label": "Item Name",
                                    "uitype": "10",
                                    "type": {
                                        "defaultValue": null
                                    }
                                },]
                                }]
```

Actual output:

example: list1:
         name :xyz
         product:123
list2:
         name :xyz
         product:abc
list3:
         name :xyz
         product:1234

Expected output:
list:
         name :xyz
         product:123,abc,1234

Java:

```
private void fetchJSONForSales(){

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                sessionId = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("sessionId");
                String operation = "syncModuleRecords";
                String module = "Potentials";
                String syncToken="";
                String mode="public";
                final GetNoticeDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetNoticeDataService.class);

                /** Call the method with parameter in the interface to get the notice data*/
                Call<SyncModule> call = service.GetSyncModuleList(operation, sessionId, module,syncToken,mode);

                /**Log the URL called*/
                Log.i("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");

                call.enqueue(new Callback<SyncModule>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<SyncModule> call, Response<SyncModule> response) {

                        Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

                            SyncModule syncModule = response.body();


                            String success = syncModule.getSuccess();

                            if (success.equals("true")) {
                                SyncResults results = syncModule.getResult();

                                Sync sync=results.getSync();

                                ArrayList<SyncUpdated> syncUpdateds=sync.getUpdated();

                                for(SyncUpdated syncUpdated:syncUpdateds){

                                    ArrayList<SyncBlocks> syncBlocks=syncUpdated.getBlocks();
                                    String title = "";
                                    String value = "";
                                    String potentialValue = "";
                                    String potentialNo = "";
                                    String assigned = "";
                                    String contact = "";
                                    String location = "";
                                    String related = "";
                                    String winprobValue = "";
                                    String valueAndQty = "";
                                    String productValue = "";
                                    String quantity = "";
                                    String salesstageValue="";
                                    String employee="";
                                    String leadsource="";
                                    String remark_sales_person="";
                                    String segment="";
                                    String modality="";
                                    String circle="";
                                    String prospect_type="",equ_details="",sale_type="",createdtime="",modifiedtime="",modifiedby="",closingdate="",exp_delivery_date="",pndt="",demo_done="",s_i="",demo_date="",fun_req="",site_read="",
                                            support_person="",support_type="",opportunity_type="",department="",rating="",interest_type="",
                                            txt_adj="",hdnS_H_Amount="",pre_tax_total="",hdnSubTotal="",listprice="",comment="",discount_amount="",tax1="",tax2="",tax3="",lost_reason="",
                                            competition_name="",price_quoted="",general_remark="",description="",termsnconditions="";
                                    String mobie = sharedPreferences.getString("mobiles", null);

                                    for (SyncBlocks syncBlocks1 : syncBlocks) {
                                        String label = syncBlocks1.getLabel();
                                        //Basic Information
                                        if (label.equals("Basic Information")) {
                                            ArrayList<SynFields> synFields = syncBlocks1.getFields();

                                            for (SynFields synFields1 : synFields) {

                                                String name = synFields1.getName();
                                                values = synFields1.getValue();

                                                if (name.equals("sales_stage")) {
                                                    salesstageValue = String.valueOf(values);


                                                } else if (name.equals("potentialname")) {
                                                    potentialValue = String.valueOf(values);


                                                } else if (name.equals("assigned_user_id")) {
                                                    try {
                                                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                                                        String strJson = gson.toJson(values);
                                                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
                                                        String v = jsonObject.getString("label");
//                                            assigned_tos.add(v);
                                                        assigned = v;
                                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                        Log.e("SalesStageFragment", "Exception is : " + ex.toString());
                                                    }

                                                } else if (name.equals("related_to")) {
                                                    try {
                                                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                                                        String strJson = gson.toJson(values);
                                                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
                                                        String v = jsonObject.getString("label");
//                                            assigned_tos.add(v);
                                                        related = v;
                                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                        Log.e("SalesStageFragment", "Exception is : " + ex.toString());
                                                    }

                                                } else if (name.equals("contact_id")) {
                                                    try {
                                                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                                                        String strJson = gson.toJson(values);
                                                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
                                                        String v = jsonObject.getString("label");
                                                        contact = v;
                                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                        Log.e("SalesStageFragment", "Exception is : " + ex.toString());
                                                    }

                                                } else if (name.equals("potential_no")) {
                                                    potentialNo = String.valueOf(values);

                                                } else if (name.equals("location")) {
                                                    location = String.valueOf(values);

                                                }else if (name.equals("employee")) {
                                                    employee = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("leadsource")) {
                                                    leadsource = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("cf_954")) {
                                                    remark_sales_person = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("segment")) {
                                                    segment = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("modality")) {
                                                    modality = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("circle")) {
                                                    circle = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }


                                            }
                                        } else if (label.equals("Opportunity Details")) {
                                            ArrayList<SynFields> synFields = syncBlocks1.getFields();
                                            for (SynFields synFields1 : synFields) {

                                                String name = synFields1.getName();
                                                values = synFields1.getValue();

                                                if (name.equals("cf_996")) {
                                                    title = String.valueOf(values);
                                                } else if (name.equals("cf_897")) {
                                                    winprobValue = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("cf_960")) {
                                                    prospect_type = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("cf_1010")) {
                                                    equ_details = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("cf_992")) {
                                                    sale_type = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("createdtime")) {
                                                    createdtime = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("modifiedtime")) {
                                                    modifiedtime = String.valueOf(values);
                                                } else if (name.equals("modifiedby")) {
                                                    try {
                                                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                                                        String strJson = gson.toJson(values);
                                                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
                                                        String v = jsonObject.getString("label");
                                                        modifiedby = v;
                                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                        Log.e("SalesStageFragment", "Exception is : " + ex.toString());
                                                    }

                                                }else if (name.equals("closingdate")) {
                                                    closingdate = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("cf_1000")) {
                                                    exp_delivery_date = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("cf_998")) {
                                                    pndt = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("demo_done")) {
                                                    demo_done = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("cf_903")) {
                                                    s_i = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("demo_date")) {
                                                    demo_date = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("cf_899")) {
                                                    fun_req = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("cf_1002")) {
                                                    site_read = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("cf_1004")) {
                                                    support_person = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("cf_1006")) {
                                                    support_type = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }else if (name.equals("opportunity_type")) {
                                                    opportunity_type = String.valueOf(values);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }


                                    String rupee = getResources().getString(R.string.Rs);
                                    int paswd = (int) Double.parseDouble(quantity);
                                    String qty=String.valueOf(paswd);
                                    ModelTest modelTest = new ModelTest(potentialValue,related,assigned,contact,location,productValue,rupee.concat(valueAndQty),
                                            potentialNo,mobie,competition_name,circle,closingdate,comment,createdtime,demo_date,demo_done,department
                                            ,description,discount_amount,equ_details,employee,exp_delivery_date,fun_req,general_remark,hdnS_H_Amount,hdnSubTotal,
                                            interest_type,lost_reason,leadsource,listprice,modality,modifiedby,modifiedtime,opportunity_type,pre_tax_total,pndt,price_quoted,prospect_type,
                                            rating,remark_sales_person,sale_type,support_type,s_i,segment,site_read,txt_adj,tax1,tax2,tax3,termsnconditions,winprobValue,support_person,qty,salesstageValue);
                                    if(salesstageValue.equals("Opportunity")){

                                        listSalesStageOpportunity.add(modelTest);
                                        opportunityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Can you share a sample response ?.

Comment: Expected output shared by you is not cleared. You said you want to display only the names in the recycler view. If I'm correct you want to display the unique data only. I mean for list items with same name, you just want 1 name with all products with that name, Right?

Comment: @SatyamKamboj see my edit post

Comment: @avinash shared json response

Comment: Use map<String, List<Product>> to keep the value (name vs List of product). Then loop over this map to create a list of SyncBlocks (Object should contain the name and list of product ). Pass this list to recyclerview to populate the value.

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing the complete model class i.e "modelTest object" to the adapter by adding it to "listSalesStageOpportunity list". All you have to change is your layout. Inflate the recycler view for item containing the names only that you want to show. If you are creating different textviews in recycler view for each data then you just need to setVisibility to View.VISIBLE for names only or you can do so by declaring it in XML layout.

Comment: I am not taking about View.VISIBLE

Comment: problem is not with layout

Answer (score -2):

HI you need to add the check there where do you want to select the name

```
 if("name").equals.("xyz"){
 append("data yo want to append")
 }
```